# jquery changing the dynamically created list

Tags: jquery

I am creating using Jquery some lists.
There is 1 text boxes. user gives some data.
when ever user does press Button , that data is copied and added to the div.

```
$("#Add").click(function(){
   var val = $('[name=Variablename]').val();
     var masterHTML = '<input type="checkbox" name="'+val+'">'+val+'   '+val+'  '+'<br>';
                $("#main").append( masterHTML);
          });
```

now the list can be big say example:

```
sampletext1
sampletext2
sampletext3
sampletext4
sampletext5
sampletext6
```

next to each there will be a check button.
as this is all dynamic data.
so when a user checks say sampletext1. how can I get that data.
basically I am looking at getting that data display on the text box so that user can update sampletext1 to sampletext1update and post it back.

how can I do that .
I am not using tables (or) forms. just div and adding text with check button

the div main is :

```
<div id="main">
</br>
</div>
```

Comment: You can add a click handler to the check button and then look for the list item or table cell that contains that button (use `.closest`) then look inside that for the text.

Comment: Show the (representative) HTML that's created which contains the newly-added text; we're *pretty* good, but we're not psychic, yet. Unfortunately.

Comment: and your code should give error.. as `val1 is undefined`... coz i don't see it is defined anywhere in your codes

Comment: @ David Thomas, @bipen. added the div code for main.as this is dynamic  I am not sure how I can show the HTML when I see the sourcedata I dont see. val1 is a typo -sorry

Comment: ok fine... u edited your post.. now its fine.. :):)

Answer (score 1):

one way... give all your dynamically generated checkbox a class(same class)..say `checkboxClass`...  and call click event for that

```
$('#main').on('change','.checkboxClass',function(){
   if($(this).is(':checked')){
       alert($(this).val());
    }
   });
```

and you need to define `value` attribute of checkbox for this to work (which is missing in above code)....again since this is checkbox user can choose multiple...have you thought about that..??

**updated**

then create a button dynamically along with checkbox with same class.. hide it ...

```
 $("#Add").click(function(){
     var val = $('[name=Variablename]').val();
     var masterHTML = '<input class="checkboxClass" type="checkbox" value="'+val+'" name="'+val+'">'+val+'   '+val+'  '+ '<button class="buttonClass">update</button><br>';
     $("#main").append( masterHTML);
      $('.buttonClass').hide(); //hide button
  });   


  $('#main').on('change','.checkboxClass',function(){
    $('.buttonClass').hide(); //make sure all other button is hidden
    if($(this).is(':checked')){ //<--here missed bracket
        $(this).next('.buttonClass').show(); //show the button that is just clicked
    }
   });

  //code to update on click of button
  $('#main').on('click','.buttonClass',function(){
       $('#yourtextBoxId').val($(this).prev().val());
  });
```

Comment: Thanks Bipen Actually I want the user to select the "check box" and than there wil be modify button. that modify button when pressed will update the textBox with the checked data ..which usecan press and do a update.

Comment: I am getting syntaxError at .on am I missing anything

Comment: oppsss.. sorry my bad.. i missed the closing bracket of `if`

Comment: trying only this 
     $('#main').on('change','.checkboxClass',function(){
   if($(this).is(':checked')){ 
   {
    $(this).next('.buttonClass').show(); //show the button that is just clicked
   }
     });
 still gives syntax error

Comment: Thanks bipen for replies ..looks I am missing some thing now it gives:TypeError: $(...).on is not a function at the line:   $('#main').on('change','.checkboxClass',function(){

Comment: ok here you go... http://jsfiddle.net/PVYEN/  ..check this out.. example.:) :)..`$() is not a function` looks like you are loading old version of jquery.. make sure you load the latest jquery file

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle link. I have added a variabe. than did button sdf. its added than checked. than update button has come did a update. how can I override the data that I modified in the selectedvariable